# My fundamental purpose in life is (exploring vs explore) new things

Tags: grammar

I wonder which sentence is correct out of these three sentence below and why. This grammar structure has been eating me away...! thanks in advance!

> 1. My fundamental purpose in life is **exploring** new things
> 2. My fundamental purpose in life is **explore** new things
> 3. My fundamental purpose in life is **to explore** new things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "purpose" is a noun, whatever follows "is" must function as a noun. Therefore 1 and 3 are correct, and 2 is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much!